# Is there any problem with my validate function for my sudoku simulator?

Tags: python, algorithm, validation, sudoku

I am recently building a sudoku simulator using python and I am confused about why my validate function does not work as intended. I tried using another validate method using 3 for loops and it worked so I think there is no problem with my solve method.
Basically if there is a same number on the same row, column, or diagonal lines, it will return False, else True

```
def validate1(grid, r, c, val):
    var = 0
    r_up = r-var
    r_down = r+var
    c_right = c+var
    c_left = c-var
    while(r_up>=0 or r_down<=8 or c_right<=8 or c_left>=0):
        if(r_up>=0):
            if(grid[r_up][c]==val):
                return False
        if(r_down<=8):
            #print("down" + str(grid[r_down][c]))
            if(grid[r_down][c]==val):
                return False
        if(c_right<=8):
            if(grid[r][c_right]==val):
                return False
        if(c_left>=0):
            if(grid[r][c_left]==val):
                return False
        if(r_up>=0 and c_right<=8):
            if(grid[r_up][c_right]==val):
                return False
        if(r_up>=0 and c_left>=0):
            if(grid[r_up][c_left]==val):
                return False
        if(r_down<=8 and c_right<=8):
            if(grid[r_down][c_right]==val):
                return False
        if(r_down<=8 and c_left>=0):
            if(grid[r_down][c_left]==val):
                return False
        var = var + 1
        r_up = r-var
        r_down = r+var
        c_right = c+var
        c_left = c-var
    return True
```

Comment: You are checking diagonals but they don't matter in a Sudoku. Instead you have to check the 3x3 block the value is in.

Comment: oh I misunderstood Sudoku, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to figure out the issue, I would suggest making the function simpler (and more Pythonic):

```
def validate1(grid,r,c,val):
    if val in grid[r] : return False
    if val in (row[c] for row in grid): return False
    if any(val in row[c//3*3:][:3] for row in grid[r//3*3:][:3]): return False
    return True
```

However, checking the conflicts like this is not the fastest way to do it.  What you can do is maintain 27 sets of used numbers corresponding to the exclusive groups on the board.  Each position maps to 3 of these groups (row,column,block) so you can quickly add the placed numbers to them and also quickly check for presence of a conflicting number using set memberships. This can be further improved by combining numbers with their group index allowing you to manage conflicts using a single set of 243 groupID-number pairs.  With this, you can write a very compact sudoku solver with backtracking that brute forces its way to the solution:

```
def shortSudokuSolve(board):
    size    = len(board)
    block   = int(size**0.5)
    board   = [n for row in board for n in row ]      
    span    = { (n,p): { (g,n)  for g in (n>0)*[p//size, size+p%size, 2*size+p%size//block+p//size//block*block] }
                for p in range(size*size) for n in range(size+1) }
    empties = [i for i,n in enumerate(board) if n==0 ]
    used    = {gn for p,n in enumerate(board) for gn in span[n,p] if n}
    empty   = 0
    while empty>=0 and empty<len(empties):
        pos        = empties[empty]
        used      -= span[board[pos],pos]
        board[pos] = next((n for n in range(board[pos]+1,size+1) if not span[n,pos]&used),0)
        used      |= span[board[pos],pos]
        empty     += 1 if board[pos] else -1
    return [board[r:r+size] for r in range(0,size*size,size)]
```